# Fatal error: GL/glfw.h: no such file or directory exsists

Tags: opengl, compilation, mingw

I installed GLFW on MinGW and followed the tutorial on the GLFW website on how to write code with Opengl (http://www.glfw.org/GLFWUsersGuide277.pdf). Then when I tried to compile the code MinGW reply's with (Fatal error:gl\glfw.h: No such file or directory exists compilation terminated).

Here's the website's code that I compiled

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int running = GL_TRUE;
// Initialize GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
 exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
// Open an OpenGL window
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 300,300, 0,0,0,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
glfwTerminate();
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
// Main loop
while( running )
{
// OpenGL rendering goes here...
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
// Swap front and back rendering buffers
glfwSwapBuffers();
// Check if ESC key was pressed or window was closed
running = !glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) &&
glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED );
}
// Close window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();
// Exit program
exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it on [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

But for those, who found this question by searching for the same error on debian systems, you need the *portable library for OpenGL, window and input (development files)*:

```
apt-get install libglfw-dev
```

Comment: MinGW is a compiler suite for Windows. Unless OP is cross compiling on a Debian based system (Debian, one of the Ubuntu-Flavours) there's no `apt` package manager around. And in case OP uses MSys on Windows, then the package manager being used would be `pacman`, not `apt`. And if OP is actually cross compiling, then `apt-get install libglfw-dev` won't do the trick either, because that one installs only the **Linux** relevant development files; for targeting Windows you need something completely different, you'd normally not find in a Linux package repository.

Comment: For info: if you need `glfw3.h`, install `libglfw3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

> I installed GLFW on MinGW

Obviously something in your installation went wrong. How exactly did you install GLFW? What were the exact steps you took starting with the download?